# How print the lines of file if string are found inside with python

Tags: python, file, search

I want to print the lines when giving string are found in a txt file.I have a txt file like that.

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
--
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

The string to find is `AP/VLAN` i wrote this code but the problem is the code stop at the first string found and i need to print all lines where `AP/VLAN` is found.

```
findString = "AP/VLAN"

with open('interfaces.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:

        if line.find(findString) != -1:
            print('String Found in Line Number:', lines.index(line) + 1)
            print('Line Content:', line)
```

Comment: Your code works for me, I'm getting two results. Do you have any error?

Comment: using python 3.10.11, your code runs fine, outputs every instance of found string

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner version of your code using `enumerate` rather than `.index()` as you will encounter a bug of printing the first index of found string instance rather than the current iteration of the loop. Also used the `in` operator instead of `.find()` function.

```
findString = "AP/VLAN"

with open('eg.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line_num, line_context in enumerate(lines):
        if findString in line_context:
            print(f'String Found in Line Number: {line_num+1}\nLine Content: {line_context.strip()}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ! i forgot enumerate...

Answer (score 0):

The `index()` method will return the first index of given value.
So `lines.index(line)` would always return 5.
In this case you can use `enumerate()` in your code, like this:

```py
findString = "AP/VLAN"

with open('interfaces.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):

        if line.find(findString) != -1:
            print('String Found in Line Number:', lines.index() + 1)
            print('Line Content:', line)
```

Comment: If you do not need `lines` afterwards, you do not need to use `readlines`. Since a text file is iterable, a simple `for index, line in enumerate(f):` is sufficient.